# How to validate a password does not accept spaces with regex

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, passwords

I have this regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^\w\*]).{6,20}$
```

this expression validates the password bring me letters, numbers and special characters , but I need to also validate that the password does not contain spaces

example:

Password allowed: over5+flow

Password not allowed: over5 +flow

Comment: Out of curiosity... Why shouldn't a password contain spaces?  It's a valid character like any other.  Doesn't reducing the set of valid characters also reduce the potential complexity of the password?

Comment: User requirements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `.` to `[^\s]`.  This will match only non-space characters.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^\w\*])[^\s]{6,20}$
```